# Not able to configure SCT Data extractor agent for SQL Server warehouse

Tags: aws-sct

I am not able to configure Extractor agent for Microsoft SQL Server. I get the below error while configuring the agent:

> Warehouse vendor : Microsoft SQL Server AWS DMS doesn't support data
>   warehouses from the specified vendor. Enter one of the supported data
>   warehouse vendors: Oracle, Teradata, Netezza, Microsoft SQL Server,
>   Greenplum, Vertica. To keep the current value, press Enter...

Even though I am giving the right warehouse vendor i.e. Microsoft SQL Server, it is still not getting picked and giving the above mentioned error.

Thanks in advance :)